# In MS Excel, how can I create a bubble chart where the color of the bubbles match the color of a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, colors

I would like to illustrate a fourth variable (x axis, y axis, bubble size, bubble color), but do not want to artificially split the series into pre-defined groups based on a set of thresholds. Rather, I want each bubble to reflect the particular colors of a cell (which will be colored through conditional formatting based on the fourth variable).

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Enter data & Fill colors.
2. click **Insert**, **Insert Scatter (X, Y)** or 
   **Bubble chart**, and select bubble chart.
3. Right click at the chart and click **Select 
   Data** from the menu.
4. From the **Select Data Source** Click **Add** 
   & select relative cells for **Data Series** .
5. For First text box select cell `A1` & below 
   cells for other Text Boxes like `A2, A3, A4`.
6. Repeat step 5 for Column `B` & `C` and Finish 
   with **Ok.**
7. Copy & Paste this VB code as Standard Module 
   with the Sheet.

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub ColorChartSeries()
   Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long
   Dim theBubbles As Range
   Dim theChart As Chart
   Dim theSeries As Series
   Dim thePoint As Point

   Set theChart = ActiveChart

   If (theChart.ChartType <> xlBubble And theChart.ChartType <> xlBubble3DEffect) Then
       MsgBox "This works only for bubble charts!"
       End
   End If

   For Each theSeries In theChart.SeriesCollection
       Set theBubbles = Range(theSeries.BubbleSizes)
       iRow = theBubbles.Row - 1
       iCol = theBubbles.Column
       For Each thePoint In theSeries.Points
           iRow = iRow + 1
           thePoint.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color
       Next thePoint
   Next theSeries

   End Sub
   ```
8. Finally, *select the Chart Area & RUN the 
   Code.*

**You get the Bubble Colors similar as the Filled 
  Cell colors.**

**Note,** *This method never gets the Conditionally Formatted Cell Colors.*

Comment: To get the conditionally formatted cell colors just use `Cells(iRow, iCol).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` instead of `Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color` :)